# Symfony OneToMany Relationship check if main (One) entity exists if inserting a new child (Many) entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Whenever I save a new child row, do I have to check if the parent ID actually exists manually? I would have thought that symfony/doctrine checks automatically and will throw an error b**ecause of the OneToMany definition**.

Example:

Main entity ("One"):

```
class Order
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderPayment", mappedBy="orderId")
     */
    private $orderPayments;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orderPayments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

Child Entity ("Many"):

```
class OrderPayment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="orderPayments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $orderId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

}
```

Whenever I insert a new OrderPayment line to the database, shouldn't Symfony check if the $orderId actually exists in the database or do I need to check manually?

Comment: You can pass your Order Entity itself into OrderPayment constructor. This will ensure that you don't have abandoned OrderPayments.

Comment: Could you explain in an answer? Simply adding a constructor that passes Order doesn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to rename `$orderId` to `$order`. Doctrine sees the relations as Entity objects, not as integers. And yes, if you save the `OrderPayment` and the `Order` does not exist, Doctrine will throw an error!

When you renamed the properties, regenerated the Entity and updated the db scheme, add an order to an orderpayment like this:

```
$order = // get order from db
$orderPayment = new OrderPayment();
$orderPayment->setOrder($order);
$em->persist($orderPayment);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: don't the targetEntity Annotation do the job? Currently it let's me save every entry even if `Order` does not exist

Comment: It is not wrong because the annotations take care as you say. It is a naming convention. Let me ask you, how do you add the Order to the OrderPayment? You should do it like this: `$orderPayment->setOrder($order);` because you add an entity object it must exist. offcourse you can save an OrderPayment without adding an Order. then Order will be null in the table

Comment: All data including the Order ID come from an form field. So it simply: `if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();`

Comment: but how can the form field with the order be filled with an ID that does not exist??

Comment: It's a manual input field. The user looks manually for payments on the bank account and then enters the orderId, value, date, ... so it could be a wrong input. At least it should check, if the orderId exists and then compare the value (which is a different topic).

Comment: Then you should make it a select by using an EntityType field. Letting users manually insert ids is not good practice as you have noticed yourself!

Comment: a select with 1000s of order IDs? Moreover there should still be some hard coded validation. HTML select fields still could be manipulated.

Comment: The EntityType does the validation for you. It does not allow different input then the values it has initially been filled with

Comment: simply changing to SelectType::class in the form builder? What about the problem, that this select will be pretty long then?

Comment: Not use SelectType but use EnityType (renders as select by default) http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html You could narrow down the contents of the select by using a custom query to fill the field. (maybe by date or you could find only orders with no related payments).

Comment: great solution, will look into it. PS: it still throws an exception because the table order is not escape properly, I guess. I already added ` to the annotations, which works well but seems to be ignored in this case. Any solution for this problem?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with not escaped properly

Comment: doctrine/symfony doesn't escape reserved words like order or limit when used as table names. Therefore they collide with the SQL functions.

Comment: set the tablename manually like this (above the classname of the Entity) `@ORM\Table(name="shop_order")` then update your DB schema

Comment: this implies renaming the table. The project however is up and running. Migrating slowly to symfony means we need backwards compatibility. But thanks you helped a lot. Will find a solution on my own :)

Comment: Hi again, can I easily get the integer `orderId` or do I need to use `order->id` (because all template files would need to be changed)

Comment: Hi again. The relations are no integers (in the db they are) but for doctrine they are entity objects. That is why you should call it `order` instead of `orderId`. So you should get the integer like this: `$orderPayment->getOrder()->getId();`

Comment: Oh great. I got it. Wouldn't however __toString() be an option? Is there any best practice or is you way already the usual convention?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your Order Entity itself into OrderPayment constructor, because OrderPayment can not exist without Order.

```
//OrderPayment
public function __construct(Order $order)
{
    $this->order = $order
    $this-createdAt = \DateTime::now();
}

//Controller or Service
$order = $orderRepository->getOrderBySomeField($field);
if ( ! $order){
    throw new HttpNotFoundException();
}
$orderPayment = new OrderPayment ($order);
$em->persist($orderPayment);
$em->flush;
```